# Object reference not set to an instance of an object with linq query EF6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-6, datatables

I am trying to implement the server side processing for the data tables plugin in C# ASP.NET MVC controller.

This is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
    IEnumerable<Device> filteredItems;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
    {
        filteredItems = _db.Devices
                           .Where(c => c.AccountCode.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
                                       c.Company.ClientId.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
                                       c.FirmVersion.Contains(param.sSearch));
    }
    else
    {
        filteredItems = _db.Devices.Include(x => x.User);
    }

    var displayedItems = filteredItems.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
    var result = from c in displayedItems
                 select new[] { 
                     c.AccountCode, 
                     c.SerialNo ?? "None", 
                     "Company Name", 
                     c.User.FirstName};

    return Json(new { sEcho = param.sEcho,
                      iTotalRecords = _db.Devices.Count(),
                      iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredItems.Count(),
                      aaData = result }, 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

I am getting an error on the line where I select from `displayedItems`.
I have debugged and found that the issue is specifically with `c.User.Firstname`

I have a feeling this is due to a lazy loading issue or something to do with the EF evaluates.

So my Question is why is EF giving me a null reference exception when I try and access the virtual Object `User` I have even explicitly included it?

I am using EF 6.1

And yes I know the async is invalid here. I was hoping to do async database calls here. So if someone can point out to me where to add those I would also appreciate it.

Comment: @Albireo I don't believe that is a duplicate of my question. My issue is relating specifically to linq and EF.

Comment: You should start by breaking your linq query into multiple lines and multiple variables, so you can see exactly which part of the linq is failing. This is a basic NullReferenceException debug until you can prove otherwise. So @Albireo is correct to suggest the possible duplication.

Comment: @PeteGarafano I have stated in the Question which line it is. `c.User.Firstname`

Comment: var displayedItems = filteredItems.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).toList(); should evaluate and then c.User.Firstname would be available.

Comment: Then I don't really understand what your question is about. What are you asking for here?

Comment: You're using EF, have you verified the input data is valid? You are 100% positive that, before the data goes into EF, `c.User.Firstname` is not null?

Comment: Could it be because you don't do `Include(x=>x.User)` in the `if` statement, only in the `else`?

Comment: @PeteGarafano Even if username its self was null It should not throw exception as I am not calling `.toString()` or anything on it. But yes as a matter of fact. It does have a value. I do believe this is due to lazy loading.

Comment: @juharr Well Spotted. Unfortunately I am not hitting the if statement in my debug. So that isnt the issue, But I will look into that for when I start searching.

Comment: `filteredItems` should be an `IQueryable`, not an `IEnumerable`.  You're doing almost all of your query in linq to objects, not using EF, when you should be doing pretty much all of this work on the DB side of things.

Comment: Just try @akfkmupiwu suggestion, call `ToList()` on `displayedItems`, it might help `var displayedItems = filteredItems.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).ToList();`.

Comment: @Servy That makes sense, I have changed it and I am now getting: `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.`

Comment: @Zapnologica I would think that the error message is pretty self explanatory as to what's wrong and what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: @michaelmoore I agree, however do I not want EF to do my quesry? If i call .tolist() before I do the take. it will pull the whole list from the db?

Comment: @michaelmoore No, actually, in fact it's important that those operation *not* be executed on the client side here.  The fact that they are is exactly why it's failing with a NRE, not that the operation makes sense to do on the client side in the first place.

Comment: @Zapnologica yes what Servy is saying is right, you should let EF to do operations for you.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you, I missed the part that filteredItems were declared as `IEnumerable<T>`.